# integrating java with C#.net

Tags: c#, java, .net, api

Is following thing possible?if yes how?
I have some core functionality already implemented in Java. Now I want to create a GUI for it.
I am finding it difficult to make a  GUI in Java using Swing. I can build a GUI easily in C#.net.
So I was thinking if it was possible to create a library in Java that I can access from my C# code.
Shorty: `my java code will provide some API and then my C# program must be able to call those APIs.`

How do I do this?

Comment: I find WinForms absolutely awful to work with and Swing *just about* as bad. That being said, if GUI in .NET is so easy and in Java it is so hard, what is the difference? -- Perhaps solving this issue could help with UI dev (although it does avoid the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what your java library does and if it uses many third party components, but thanks to [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html) you could compile a jar file into a .NET assembly. I've used this approach to incorporate the [xhtmlrenderer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) java library into a C# application with success.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have properly structured your Java code, creating a [Web Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) bridge between the two could be the way to go. For example you could expose the Java API through a [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP_(protocol)) and simply make the C# UI depend on that.

The great side in this solution of course is that if you do it this way, you can replace the UI completely at any point you want to, downside is that you would have to run the Java part separately in a context such a servlet container which may be quite heavyweight for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

Have a look at JNBrige: http://www.jnbridge.com/

But, to be honest, I think it would be better to rewrite your APIs in .Net. Makes it easier in the end imho. I prefer working in one environment and not having to maintain things at different places.

Comment: I second the idea of rewriting your APIs in C#. Your idea just oozes with potential testing and maintenance issues.

Answer (score 1):

have you considered using webservices?  You could also execute a java program using something like:

```
private void calljava(object ob,EventArgs arg)
    {
        Process.Start("j.bat");
    }
```

There is also [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/index.htm)

Just a few ideas....